# Streaming from webcam on OS X - what technology to use?

Tags: macos, streaming, real-time, webcam, quicktime

I'm building a videoconferencing  application in OS X.

What technology would be best to use for real-time streaming video/audio captured from webcam/microphone in OS X?

So far I was unsuccessful with these methods:

- using QTKit I captured the media, but there isn't a way to stream it (without using the QTSS which is too bloaty and hard to control programmatically).
- using QT Java I got everything (almost) working, but the library is deprecated, it crashes every once in a while, signals memory leaking and there isn't a way to save preferences from a settings dialog
- I installed gstreamer using Macports, but there isn't a working osxvideosrc (or audio for that matter)

My next target is VLC because it can access the webcam in OS X, but I'm not sure will it give me what I need - can I control it fully over an API and can I display the stream inside a Cocoa application (using QTKit's player)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could of points:

- Consider [Flex](http://www.adobe.com/products/flex/)/Flash and possible [Adobe Air](http://www.adobe.com/products/air/).  Many people have written videoconferencing applications this way.
- QT for Java is dated and not going anywhere.
- VLC is a solid option.  Stable, well known, powerful, and very mature.

Comment: thanks for the advice. I will consider using Flex/Flash in the future. An update is that VLCkit can be used for stream playback in OS X and it's ligthly faster than QTKit, but sound didn't work. Anyway, if someone wants to try it, I put an installation guide [here](http://kermit.epska.org/node/13).

Comment: @Dražen Lučanin: Sound didn't work...hmmm...have a look at the sound codec maybe?  QT is very particular about the codecs it supports.

Comment: No, sound didn't work in **VLCKit**. The funny thing is that when I played the same stream in VLC player it worked, which is funny since I gave them both the same URL and they share code (or at least should). It also worked in QTKit, but the latency there is hardcoded by the Apple devs at 5 seconds so it's unusable for RTS.